# Reducible/Irreducible 2x2 matrices

Tags: matrices, invariant-subspace

as far as I understand, one considers that an irreducible matrix only contains trivial invariant subspaces (the whole space, the null vector and its eigenvectors). So, are there 2x2 reducible matrices?, they only contain trivial invariant spaces. Looking for examples of reducible/irreducible matrices, I only find at most 3x3 matrices.

Thanks in advance. Sorry if I am being imprecise.

Answer (score 0):

How about
$A=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0\\ 
  1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$?

$A^n=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0\\ 
  n & 1
\end{pmatrix}$.